# Basics: how to create templates with Template Project Plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm missing something very basic.  I have Jenkins 1.607 and recently installed Template Project Plugin 1.5.1 but don't see a way to create templates.  This is what I see, when I select New Job:

[image]

There is Workflow Template above, but no Project Template.  I'm not sure what I should be looking for...

Searching online I found the following (http://mark.gg/2013/05/03/jenkins-and-templates/):

> "To use the template plugin, you create a job that will have modules - source code management (SCM), builders, publishers - that will be used by other projects."

However, following instructions from the above page, Jenkins creates a regular job - I don't see a way to specify modules.  Here is the SCM section in my job that should become a template:

[image: Template job SCM section]

**New Edit: ==>>** I have several jobs with SCM section defined.  Below is a newly created, Freestyle job where I want to use the SCM from an already defined job, but there is no such choice:

[image: New job where I want to use SCM template]

For the record, here is a snapshot of installed template plugins:

[image: Installed Template Plugins]

Appreciate any pointers on how to "create a job that will have modules".

**Edit:** upgraded Jenkins to the latest 1.631 - same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The template project is a classic Jenkins job.
In this job, please define all the module you want to use in clone jobs (SCM, build, post build, ...):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next, create a new job and select the template modules:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does it solve your problem? :)

Comment: I have many jobs defined.  I have just created a new Freestyle Project but I don't see an option to use SCM or any other module from another proeject.   I'm going to add a snapshot to the original question above.

Comment: The good news is that I do see "Use builders/publishers from another project" for Bulid and Post-build Actions.  Thank you for pointing this out.  Any idea why SCM module is not available?

Comment: No pb for helping :) About the SCM module, did you define some SCM settings in your template job?

Comment: Yes, the SCM module is defined and working in several jobs, that are freestyle jobs.  I have just created a new job with nothing but scm configured - my template.  I then created a new freestyle job - still the choices are as above: only None, Git and Subversion.

Comment: When I did some tests, I saw that if you define a template with a freestyle project, and if you try to use it in a Maven project, it's not working very well :(

Comment: Thanks for checking.  Is there a better choice for a template than freestyle project?  Specifically for defining SCM?  It simply does not work for me.

Comment: In my company, instead of using the template plugin, I've used the copy job plugin. I'm using a template with some keywords. I've created a job using the copy job plugin: it create a new job based on my template and it replaces all the keywords with the new values. It works well :)

Comment: It seems that Template Project Plugin can only reference projects in the top level(root) of Jenkins?. Is it so or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I installed Jenkins 1.638 and ran into the same problem using an SCM template from an already defined job because it didn't show up in the option list. Digging deeper the "System Log" in the "Manage Jenkins" section had some more information as to why.

```
Nov 13, 2015 3:22:53 PM INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Augmented all extensions

Nov 13, 2015 3:22:58 PM WARNING hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error

Failed to instantiate Key[type=hudson.plugins.templateproject.ProxySCM$DescriptorImpl, annotation=[none]]; skipping this component
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jenkinsci/plugins/multiplescms/MultiSCMRevisionState
  at hudson.plugins.templateproject.ProxySCM$DescriptorImpl.<init>(ProxySCM.java:112)
```

Turns out there is a dependency on the plugin "Multiple SCMs Plugin". Install that plugin and the option shows up correctly in the Jenkins job configuration using the version 1.5.1 of the Template Project plugin.

[SCM Options Before installing the Multiple SCM Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G528.png)

[SCM Options After installing the Multiple SCM Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Kk8.png)

Comment: These issues on the plugin ([1](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31712) [2](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30243)) on the plugin seem relevant.

Answer (score -2):

Templates are not included in the free (community) version of Jenkins. Instead, Cloudbees.com offers templates in its paid "Jenkins for the Enterprise" products and services.

Comment: Are you saying that even though I installed this plugin it basically does nothing in the community edition?  Why make it an available plugin then?  Also, nothing at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin says that it only works in enterprise edition.

Comment: You're confusing a similarly named feature in the paid version.